# Using didSet to set a NSDate variable when UIDatePicker's date is changed

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I am trying to use the didSet property observer to change the (NSDate variable) dueDate's NSDate whenever the UIDatePicker's date is changed in my iOS Swift app. To see if the dueDate was changed accordingly, I want it to display the dueDate on the console. However, my code doesn't do anything at all:

```
var dueDate = NSDate() {
    didSet {
        dueDate = datePicker.date
        print("\(dueDate)")
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how do you want to change dueDate when you want to do this only when dueDate is set somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't seem to observe the `UIDatePicker` value changes. You should:

1-Add your `UIViewController` as a target for the `ValueChanged` event on your `UIDatePicker`:

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

2-When the event is trigged, you have to forward the value to `dueDate`:

```
func datePickerValueChanged() {
     self.dueDate = datePicker.date
}
```

Here is a fully working example:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

    var dueDate = NSDate() {
        didSet {
            print("New due date value: \(dueDate)")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.datePickerValueChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)

    }
    func datePickerValueChanged() {
        self.dueDate = datePicker.date
    }
}
```